# Replace Local Links, Keep External Links

Tags: php, regex, parsing, regex-lookarounds

I have an API call that essentially returns the HTML of a hosted wiki application page. I'm then doing some substr, str_replace and preg_replace kung-fu to format it as per my sites style guides.

I do one set of calls to format my left nav (changing a link to pageX to my wikiParse?page=pageX type of thing). I can safely do this on the left nav. In the body text, however, I cannot safely assume a link is a link to an internal page. It could very well be a link to an external resource. So I need to do a preg_replace that matches href= that is not followed by http://.

Here is my stab at it:

```
$result = preg_replace('href\=\"(?!http\:\/\/)','href="bla?id=',$result);
```

This seems to strip out the entire contents on the page. Anyone see where I slipped up? I don't think I'm too far off, just can't see where to go next.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`preg_*` functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) expect [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php). The structural difference to normal regular expressions is that the expression itself is wrapped into delimiters that separate the expression from possible [modifiers](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). The classic delimiter is the `/` but PHP allows any other non-alphanumeric character except the backslash character. See also [Intruduction to PCRE in PHP](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php).

So try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/href="(?!http:\/\/)/', 'href="bla?id=', $result);
```

Here `href="(?!http://)` is the regular expression. But as we use `/` as delimiters, the occurences of `/` inside the regular expression must be escaped using backslashes.

Comment: Good eye! I knew it'd be something obvious...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is missing starting and ending delimiters (by default '/');

```
$result = preg_replace('/href\=\"(?!http\:\/\/)/','href="bla?id=',$result);
```